# Escape single quote in Angular UI

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to check and therefore not display in the Angular template view if `account.DayTimePhone` variable has a single quote in it.

This is my code:

```
 <tr ng-if="account.DaytimePhone!=='' && !(account.DaytimePhone).includes(')">
  <td class="col-md-6">Daytime Phone</td>
 </tr>
```

I however get an error due to the unescaped single quote character.

I also tried:

```
!(account.DaytimePhone).includes(\')
```

Would appreciate any ideas on how to check for single quotes appearing in the variable in the view. Thanks in advance.

I know it’s easy to do in back end and have also tried RegEx but same problem in view.

I tried many different ways including single quotes and double and for some reason both these lines get a print out:

```
<tr ng-if="!account.DaytimePhone.includes('\'')">
                                first
</tr>
 <tr ng-if="account.DaytimePhone.includes('\'')">
                               second
 </tr>
```

To pinpoint the question: 
EASIEST WAY TO CHECK FOR SINGLE QUOTES IN ANGULAR VIEW

[image]

Comment: maybe try `.includes('\'')`

Comment: `'` introduces the start of a string. But you're never ending it and your string also doesn't contain anything. A string literal representing a single quote would be `"'"` or `'\''`.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I should have commented that I already tried this and ended up where I was with just putting in a quote. By putting it in the way you suggest I get no validation at all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with something like this:

`!(account.DaytimePhone).includes("'")`

Basically, put the single quote in double quotes (`"'"`)

Comment: Had tried this but as you can see the section is in double quotes already so also throws error

Comment: this can't work since the whole statement is already placed within HTML-attribute double quotes. The first one of `includes("")` whould end the HTML-attribute value.

Comment: thanks MA-Maddin- exactly my point -> seemingly trivial thing to achieve but not so

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using :

```
ad.Accountdetails.value.Account.DaytimePhone !== '\''
```

All other attempts to use .include and .length, and .indexOf failed

Hope it helps someone